# How to get list output in range

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How can we get list output in range ?

suppose n=4 and k =3

so how can we get list [1,2,3,1]  where length of array will be n and k is range (1....k)

ex -2

if n=5 and k=3

list will be [1,2,3,1,2]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to cycle on the values of a range from 1 to k, then use [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.isclice)
to get n values from it:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

k = 3
n = 7

k_cycle = cycle(range(1, k+1))

out = list(islice(k_cycle, n))

print(out)
# [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: I like your pure functional solution.

Answer (score 1):

Short solution:

```
[i % k + 1 for i in range(n)]
```

and another a bit longer solution:

```
[i for j in range((n + k - 1) // k) for i in range(1, k + 1)][:n]
```

and similar to above but expressed differently

```
(list(range(1, k + 1)) * ((n + k - 1) // k))[:n]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
n,k = map(int,input().strip().split())
x=[]
for i in range(n):
    x.append(1+i%k)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
n = 5
k = 3
current_number = 1
ls = []
for count in range(n):
    ls.append(current_number)
    current_number = ((current_number) % k) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

```
def rangelist(n, k):
    return [i for i,_ in zip(cycle(range(1,k+1)), range(n))]
rangelist(n=5,k=3)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done with `itertools`:

```
import itertools  
k,n = 3, 5    
result = []    
# defining iterator  
iterators = itertools.cycle(list(range(1,k+1)))  
# for in loop  
for i in range(n):    
    x.append(next(iterators))
```

print(x)